# CoreData: would it be safe using NSConfinementConcurrencyType and dispatch all operations using this context on a serial dispatch queue?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Literally, this concurrency type requires an specific thread, but using a serial queue would be more easy, but is it safe to use the context with a NSConfinementConcurrencyType concurrency type on a serial dispatch queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you're sure you only use that queue with the context, yes, that's completely fine.

Core Data doesn't care about the thread so much as it cares about concurrent access. If you serialize access, you're safe, however you choose to do it. You could use `NSRecursiveLock` or semaphores or whatever works for you.

Note that the newer concurrency models are queue based. `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` does *not* guarantee that operations are always performed on the same thread, even when you use `performBlock:`. They happen on a private *queue* and might run on different threads at different times. If you can manage your queue and your access well enough to do this yourself, it's reasonable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

No, having a serial queue does not guarantee the operations will execute on the same thread:

The [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) specifies

> Serial queues (also known as private dispatch queues) execute one task
>   at a time in the order in which they are added to the queue. The
>   currently executing task runs on a distinct thread (which can vary
>   from task to task) that is managed by the dispatch queue. Serial
>   queues are often used to synchronize access to a specific resource.

Why don't you just use the NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType? It will make your code cleaner and thread safe. You just need to call `-performBlock:` or `-performBlockAndWait:` when accessing the context from somewhere other than the block that initialized the context.

Comment: Correct, however in my experience a serial queue has provided the needed thread safety.  It will guarantee that only one thread is accessing the context at any given time (provided that you don't forget to use it anywhere).

Comment: That's true. It should be thread-safe enough and probably the privateQueue contexts use the same technique, but Apple doesn't recommend doing so, and in fact doesn't expose the context's private queues. Moreover in the video of the WWDC 2011 where they presented the new block APIs and the new concurrency type initializers they explicitly said not to mess up with the contexts private queues as it will break everything. I guess that's because of some special optimization and locking they do.

Comment: Yes, I used this technique before iOS 5 and the new concurrency types.  These days, I would stick to the private queue type.  I imagine Apple also says that mostly because there are thousands of idiots out there who are clueless and would just do whatever they want and then blame Apple when it doesn't work.